# Probability: Help with Intersections of probabilities.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

So in my spare time i'm restudying probability (it's been well over a year) and for some reason it just isn't "clicking" i'm sure once it does i'll be fine but untill then i seem to be stuck, as such any help in rectifying this would be much appreciated (on that note i apologise to those who may have already helped me on similiar issues and beg your patience)

From a first course in probability.

Question 3.9
"Consider 3 urns with W and R balls, Urn A has 2 W, 4 R. Urn B contains 8 W and 4 R. and Urn C has 1 W and 3 R.

If 1 ball is selected from each urn, what is the probability the ball chosen from urn A was white given that exactly 2 white balls were selected."

So! i would like to define two events:

E = the event that a white ball was selected from Urn A.

F = the event that two white balls have been selected in total.

then
$$P(E|F)=\frac{P(E\cap F)}{P(F)}$$
so i'm looking for the intersection of E and F. IE, the probability of selecting a White ball from A whilst selecting a white ball from either B or C. which basically means $P(E \cap F) \Rightarrow P(E \cap (E_{1} \cup E_{2})=P((E \cap E_{1}) \cup (E\cap E_{2})) $ where $E_{1} =$ picking a white ball from urn B and $E_{2}=$Picking a white ball from urn C. yes?

in which case i combine B and C into one urn giving
$$P(E\cap F)=\frac{{{2}\choose{1}}{{9}\choose{1}}}{{22}\choose{3}}$$
which i believe is the number of ways of choosing 1 of 2 white balls from urn A, 1 of 9 white balls from Urn $(B\cup C)$ divided by all possible combinations of choosing 3 balls from all 3 urns.

Then $$P(F)=P(E_{1} \cup E_{2})= \frac{{{9}\choose{1}}}{{16}\choose{2}}$$

but upon thinking about this. this seems wrong...because F is defined as the event of selecting two white balls in total. then shouldnt it be
$$P(F)=\frac{{{11}\choose{2}}}{{{22}\choose{3}}}$$

but both ways of thinking gives me the wrong answer anyway. where am i going wrong? (and yeah i'm going to be re-reading the chapter again anyway)

Comment: i feel like i'm making a simple mistake....

Comment: I'd say that $P(E\cap F)$ is the probability of picking one *and only one* white ball from urns $B$ and $C$. But that's the probability of picking exactly one white ball from urn $B$ plus the probability of picking exactly one white ball from urn $C$ *minus* the probability of picking exactly one white ball from *both* urns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three urns and are picking one ball from each (independently).

Let $A,B,C$ be the events of picking a white ball from each respective urn, and $\overline A,\overline B,\overline C$ their complements.

You want $\mathsf P(A\mid AB\overline C\cup A\overline BC\cup \overline ABC)~=~\dfrac{\mathsf P(AB\overline C)+\mathsf P( A\overline BC)}{\mathsf P(AB\overline C)+\mathsf P(A\overline BC)+\mathsf P(\overline ABC)}$

Where $\mathsf P(AB\overline C) = \tfrac 2{2+4}\cdot\tfrac 8{8+4}\cdot\tfrac 3{1+3}$ and so forth

Comment: Thanks for the answer.